# Create a third column in pandas for finding distance between zip codes

Tags: pandas, zipcode

I have a source_zipcode column and a destination_zipcode column in my pandas dataframe. Now using pgeocode I can get the distance between any two zipcodes. I want to create one more column called "Distance" which will store these values returned from the pegocode function.

the custom function can be something like this

```
def get_distance(x,y):
    ### Here x and y are the zipcodes
    usa_zipcodes = pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')
    distance_in_kms = usa_zipcodes.query_postal_code(x,y)
    return distance_in_kms
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
def get_distance(x, y):
    usa_zipcodes = pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')
    distance_in_kms = usa_zipcodes.query_postal_code(x.values, y.values)
    return distance_in_kms

df['Distance'] = get_distance(df['source_zipcode'], df['destination_zipcode'])
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'source_zipcode': ['56001', '48446', '98503', '14424', '28655'],
     'destination_zipcode': ['03301', '20601', '11520', '39180', '61821']}
)

df['Distance'] = get_distance(df['source_zipcode'], df['destination_zipcode'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  source_zipcode destination_zipcode     Distance
0          56001               03301  1804.015668
1          48446               20601   732.032068
2          98503               11520  3941.994944
3          14424               39180  1670.079116
4          28655               61821   753.929032
```

Comment: Nice one, Corralien!!